# IMPORT ERROR(S) OCCURRED! Exception thrown while importing JSS app Message: AddFromTemplate - Add access required

Tags: jss

Trying to import the sample jss app into the Sitecore 9.1, but getting the below error any idea why is this is ?

```
IMPORT ERROR(S) OCCURRED!
Exception thrown while importing JSS app
Exception: Sitecore.Exceptions.AccessDeniedException
Message: AddFromTemplate - Add access required (destination: {GUID}, template: {GUID})
```

Comment: Ensure that you are running console (or any other tool which you are using) as an administrator.

Comment: I think it's because you don't have add access

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error occurs when the configured JSS import user (defaults to `sitecore\JSSImport`) is authenticated, but does not have the rights to add a template.

These rights are normally granted by the `sitecore\JSS Import Service Users` group membership but it sounds like the default ACLs assigned there may be missing in your case.

Comment: Thanks Kam for inputs, for some reason after importing the 'Sitecore JavaScript Services Server for Sitecore 9.1 XP 11.0.0 rev. 181031.zip', the roles you mentioned (sitecore\JSSImport, sitecore\JSS Import Service Users) is missing in my instance.

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a bug in the Sitecore WebDeploy package `Sitecore JavaScript Services Server for Sitecore 9.1.1 XM 11.0.1 rev. 190318.scwdp`

The SQL generates a role called `sitecore\JssImport` but does not create the user or assign it to the role.

Comment: There is now a KB article about particular issue https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/650791

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue, but i had a different root cause. Because my content is serialized in unicorn i had 2 roles missing on my root.

So i had to add the following permissions to the JssImport user.
[image: JssImportUser]

Answer (score 0):

I face the similar issue with `Sitecore 10.2`.

User `sitecore\JssImport` was not present.

Re-installed `Sitecore Headless Services Server XP 19.0.0 rev. 00508.zip`.

[image]

After installing I can see this user and able to deploy sitecore jss app.